# /testforblock items in chest not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to test for a written book in a chest but I keep getting the error message: Block at -1489,64,-1510 did not have the required NBT keys. I know there is a glitch were you have to fill in every NBT tag but please don't say it is the glitch because **I filled in every tag**. My command is below and I'm playing in 1.8.8, please help me!

```
/testforblock -1489 64 -1510 minecraft:chest -1 {Items:[{id:"minecraft:written_book",Slot:0b,Damage:0s,Count:1b}]}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's look at your data tag here carefully.

```
{
  Item:
  [
    id:"minecraft:written_book",
    Slot:0b,
    Damage:0s,
    Count:1b
  }
  ]
}
```

In this expanded form, you can immediately see that something is odd about your parentheses. There is a closing curly bracket without a partner. You'll have to add `{` before `id` (which is the first tag inside the item tag). Generally, when something is wrong, expanding the command over multiple lines and indenting properly at every layer is a good idea to catch these type of errors.

Secondly, the tag containing the item tags for chests is called `Items`, plural (cf. the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk_format#Block_entity_format)).

In total, the data tag needs to be

```
{
  Items:
  [
    {
      id:"minecraft:written_book",
      Slot:0b,
      Damage:0s,
      Count:1b
    }
  ]
}
```

Or compacted for easy copy and paste:

```
{Items:[{id:"minecraft:written_book",Slot:0b,Damage:0s,Count:1b}]}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong. I have the book in the chest, I copy pasted your command, I'm confused.

Comment: Never mind. Your command actually did work,  but my book had an invalid tag. Thank you though!

Comment: You can test for it in any slot if you leave out the slot tag